# [Wix][Harvest] How to get a Guid of a matched Component and set it to an attribute in Xsl

Tags: xslt, wix, heat

Hy everyone,
 I'm using Wix  with Heat and a XslTransform file.
 I want to customize my App.config connectionString using a made UI dialog. Therefore, I use Xsl Transformation as below to add a XmlFile copy:

```
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[wix:File[@Source='$(var.SourceDir)\App.config']]">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateBaseAddress"
   Action="setValue"
   File="[I want to put here my auto generated ID for the App.config File Component]"
   SelectionLanguage="XPath"
   Permanent="yes"
   ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/"
   Name="connectionString" Value="[DatabaseConnectionString]" >
   </util:XmlFile>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried a lot of ways without a succes. Do you have how to set the matched file id to my 'File' attribute?
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the component ID there. The `File` attribute expects the path to the physical file, not MSI component ID. Here is the WiX snippet of how to achieve the similar thing (although not with `XmlFile`, but `XmlConfig` element):

```
<Component Id="ConnectionStringChanges" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}" Directory="App_Config">
  <CreateFolder/>
  <Condition>NOT Installed</Condition>
  <util:XmlConfig Id="ConnectionStringChange" ElementPath="connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='core'[\]]"
                  File="[!ConnectionStrings.config]" Name="connectionString" Action="create" Node="value" On="install"
                  PreserveModifiedDate="yes" Value="user id=[SQL_SERVER_CONFIG_USER];password=[SQL_SERVER_CONFIG_PASSWORD];Data Source=[SQL_SERVER];Database=[DBPREFIX]Core_DB" />
  </Component>
```

Couple of things to note here:

The `Directory` attribute of the `<Component>` element can be omitted in case you nest the `ConnectionStringChanges` component under the right `<Directory>` element. However, if the directory structure is auto-generated with Heat, you can use this XSL snippet to replace auto-generated ID of the `App_Config` folder with the custom one:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory[@Name='App_Config']">
  <xsl:element name="Directory" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
     <xsl:attribute name="Id">App_Config</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
```

As long as `ConnectionStrings.config` file declaration is also auto-generated, you should apply the similar trick to be able to reference the file with [`\[!ConnectionStrings.config\]` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory[@Name='App_Config']/wix:Component[wix:File[@Source='$(var.Source)\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config']]">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:attribute name="NeverOverwrite">yes</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:element name="File" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">ConnectionStrings.config</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="wix:File/@KeyPath | wix:File/@Source"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:copy>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
However I'm quite confused, I rather have a harvested App.config file in the root of my application .
 The "DatabaseConnectionString" is a Property:
        <Property Id="DatabaseConnectionString" Value="Test"/>
 Which the user changes it in my wizard:
  <Control Id="DBConnectionString" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="85"
            Width="220" Height="18" Property="DatabaseConnectionString" Text="{80}" />